# Solapamiento etiquetas dendograma

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

Estoy realizando un dendograma  de mis datos. El set de datos es este: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q8YlFyROX0WoRq_TqwtCaDn_kpNHzNnr/view?usp=sharing Este dataframe contiene 5043 valores. Esto da lugar a que el dendograma que estoy realizando tenga un aspecto como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código usado para construir el dendograma es este:

```
   dend <- femData %>%  scale %>% 
     dist %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram


   dend %>% set("labels_col", c("green", "blue")) %>% # change color
   set("labels_cex", 0.1) %>% # Change size
   plot(main = "Change the color \nand size") # plot
```

Como se puede ver he reducido al máximo el tamaño de las etiquetas pero aún asi aparece solapado.
¿Existe alguna manera de hacer que el dendograma se pueda ver mejor?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

1. La cantidad de observaciones, que hace que se comprima cada una a un nivel que no llega a discernirse cual es cual
2. Algunas distancias muy grandes entre nodos, que "comprimen" las relaciones más cercanas, como cuando tenemos "outliers",  los cluster que van entre el 0 y 1 por ejemplo, casi no se llegan a ver.

No hay muchas alternativa para resolver esto, solo te puedo sugerir:

1. Ya que el dendograma parece más ancho que alto, puedes intentar rotarlo mediante `plot(main = "Change the color \nand size", horiz=TRUE)`
2. Ajustar las etiquetas según la distancia, en tu caso que tienes mucha concentración en los nodos más cercanos, no creo que aporte más que separar las etiquetas de los "ouliers", prueba con `as.dendrogram(hang=0.02)`
3. Seguramente lo anterior no alcance, por que el problema finalmente es que el visor de gráficos de Rstudio siempre ajusta los gráficos para que se vean completos, pero tienes la posibilidad de "visualizarlos" pasando primero por un archivo al que si puedes ajustar el tamaño:

   ```
    # Acá podemos ajustar el tamaño final del gráfico
    pdf('rplot.pdf', height = 35, width = 10)

    femData %>%  
       scale %>% 
       dist %>% 
       hclust %>% 
       as.dendrogram(hang=0.02) %>% 
       set("labels_col", c("green", "blue")) %>% # change color
       set("labels_cex", 0.1) %>% # Change size
       plot(main = "Change the color \nand size",horiz=TRUE) # plot

    dev.off()
   ```

   El secreto es ajustar las dimensiones para acomodar de tal forma la gráfica d que logremos no superponer las etiquetas.
4. Lo último que puedo sugerirte, es recortar el gráfico en partes ([Aquí hay un buen ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404035/how-to-plot-dendrograms-with-large-datasets))

Answer (score 0):

El conjunto de datos no es público y requiere acceso, pero sugiero que consideres la utilización de la librería `ggrepel`: en sus [ejemplos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html) está lleno de casos de etiquetas que se solapan y potenciales soluciones. Por ejemplo podrías pensar en algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]